# Turn off multithreaded debugging in Eclipse CDT

Tags: android, eclipse, gdb

I'm trying to debug some Android stuff with Eclipse, but it always crashes when I use the android gdb in Eclipse instead of the terminal. I suspect it's because of the multi-threaded stuff. Is it possible to turn that off? (I read that the Eclipse 3.2 debugger didn't do multithreaded stuff, but I can't find the 3.2 CDT package for download anywhere ...)

Comment: Huh? Why aren't you using the android plugin, and the normal Eclipse debugger? I've never had any problems in debugging multithreaded applications.

Comment: are you sureyou dont mean ADB (Android Debug Bridge) ?

Comment: CDT is the C/C++ development plugin for Eclipse.